# How to finding a given length of runs in a series of data?

Tags: r

I'm trying to study times in which flow was operating at a given level. I would like to find when flows were above a given level for 4 or more hours. How would I go about doing this?

Sample code:

```
Date<-format(seq(as.POSIXct("2014-01-01 01:00"), as.POSIXct("2015-01-01 00:00"),     by="hour"), "%Y-%m-%d %H:%M", usetz = FALSE)
Flow<-runif(8760, 0, 2300)

IsHigh<- function(x ){
    if (x < 1600) return(0) 
    if (1600 <= x) return(1) 
}

isHighFlow = unlist(lapply(Flow, IsHigh))

df = data.frame(Date, Flow, isHighFlow )
```

I was asked to edit my questions to supply what I would like to see as an output.

I would like to see a data from such as the one below. The only issue is the hourseHighFlow is incorrect. I'm not sure how to fix the code to generation the correct hoursHighFlow.

```
temp <- df %>%
  mutate(highFlowInterval = cumsum(isHighFlow==1)) %>%
  group_by(highFlowInterval) %>%
  summarise(hoursHighFlow = n(), minDate = min(as.character(Date)), maxDate = max(as.character(Date))) 

#Then join the two tables together. 
temp2<-sqldf("SELECT * 
  FROM temp LEFT JOIN df 
  ON df.Date BETWEEN temp.minDate AND temp.maxDate")
```

Able to use subset to select the length of time running at a high flow rate.

```
t<-subset(temp2,isHighFlow==1)
t<-subset(t, hoursHighFlow>=4)
```

Comment: have a look at `rle`. It gives `lengths` in the result, like `rle(df$isHighFlow)$lengths`

Comment: Thanks That looks very useful. The problem is I would like to be able to look at those run which are bigger than 4 hours. Not just how many are there. The rle just returns run lengths  `temp<-rle(isHighFlow)` and  `df$RunLenght<- temp$lengths` returns error.

Comment: So what precisely is the desired output for this sample data? (use `set.seed()` to make random number generation reproducible).

Comment: You might want to edit that into your question.

Answer (score 2):

Put it in a data.table:

```
require(data.table)
DT <- data.table(df)
```

Mark runs and lengths:

```
DT[,`:=`(r=.GRP,rlen=.N),by={r <- rle(isHighFlow);rep(1:length(r[[1]]),r$lengths)}]
```

Subset to long runs:

```
DT[rlen>4L]
```

**How it works:**

- New columns are created in the second argument of `DT[i,j,by]` with `:=`.
- `.GRP` and `.N` are special variables for, respectively, the index and size of the `by` group.
- A `data.table` can be subset simply with `DT[i]`, unlike a `data.frame`.

Apart from subsetting, most of what works with a `data.frame` works the same on a `data.table`.

Comment: `data.table` will soon have an `rleid` function, which would simplify this to `by=rleid(isHighFlow)`

Answer (score 1):

Here is a solution using the [dplyr](http://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/dplyr/vignettes/introduction.html) package:

```
df %>%
  mutate(interval = cumsum(isHighFlow!=lag(isHighFlow, default = 0))) %>%
  group_by(interval) %>%
  summarise(hoursHighFlow = n(), minDate = min(as.character(Date)), maxDate = max(as.character(Date)), isHighFlow = mean(isHighFlow)) %>%
  filter(hoursHighFlow >= 4, isHighFlow == 1)
```

**Result:**

```
   interval hoursHighFlow          minDate          maxDate isHighFlow
1        25             4 2014-01-03 07:00 2014-01-03 10:00          1
2       117             4 2014-01-12 01:00 2014-01-12 04:00          1
3       245             6 2014-01-23 13:00 2014-01-23 18:00          1
4       401             6 2014-02-07 03:00 2014-02-07 08:00          1
5       437             5 2014-02-11 02:00 2014-02-11 06:00          1
6       441             4 2014-02-11 21:00 2014-02-12 00:00          1
7       459             4 2014-02-13 09:00 2014-02-13 12:00          1
8       487             4 2014-02-16 03:00 2014-02-16 06:00          1
9       539             7 2014-02-21 08:00 2014-02-21 14:00          1
10      567             4 2014-02-24 11:00 2014-02-24 14:00          1
..      ...           ...              ...              ...        ...
```

As Frank notes, you could achieve the same result with using `rle` to set intervals, replacing the `mutate` line with:

```
mutate(interval = rep(1:length(rle(df$isHighFlow)[[2]]),rle(df$isHighFlow)[[1]])) %>%
```

Comment: Thank you, I have almost what I would like. I would like to have a dataframe with flow data. I have edited the code to: `temp <- df %>%
  mutate(highFlowInterval = cumsum(isHighFlow==0)) %>%
  group_by(highFlowInterval) %>%
  summarise(hoursHighFlow = n(), minDate = min(as.character(Date)), maxDate = max(as.character(Date))) 

#Then join the two tables together. 
temp2<-sqldf("SELECT * 
  FROM temp LEFT JOIN df 
  ON df.Date BETWEEN temp.minDate AND temp.maxDate")` **Do you know why this is returning runs longer then they are?**

Comment: @user2946746 Try a different `by` condition when generating `highFlowInterval`, like `{r <- rle(isHighFlow);rep(1:length(r[[1]]),r$lengths)}`. I had the wrong thing in my answer before (using `cumsum`), but I think this works (in `dplyr`, as in this answer or wherever).

Comment: Because my code was wrong, sorry - good catch.  I've corrected the answer, and added a `dplyr`-friendly version of Frank's `rle` approach to counting intervals.